# NodeJS: Async comportment not wanted

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to write a little daemon that checks if there is a mail to send, do jobs if needed then sleep X seconds.

I'm not so familiar with the asynchrone way of NodeJS. So I'm lost.

```
var sleep = require('sleep');

function getMailToSend(callback){
    [...]
}

function sendmail(mail, callback) {
    [...]
}

while(true){
    sleep.sleep(10);
    getMailToSend(function(err, mail) {
        if(err) //Do log, whatever
        sendMail(mail, function(err, response) {
            if(err) //Do log...
        });

    }
```

As you can read:

1. Mails are not sent one AFTER one
2. Sleep is really freezing, so it freezes the sendmail too (ARGH)

Does somebody knows who to realized that?

**Edit after first solution of qubyte**

I have a solution but uggly one :s

```
var obj = { sent: true};

setInterval(function () {
    if(obj.sent === false){
        return;
    }
    obj.sent = false;
    getMailToSend(function(err, mail) {
        sendMail(function(err, response){
        obj.sent = true;
        });
    });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're asking for is for one mail to complete before sending the next, then something like this async function may solve your issue:

```
function handleMail (callback) {
    function getMailToSend() {
        // Logic to get mail.

        // No mail left to process.
        if (!mail) {
            return callback();
        }

        sendMail(mail);
    }

    function sendMail(mail) {
        // Logic to send the mail.

        getMailToSend();
    }

    // Get the get-send cycle started.
    getMailToSend();
}
```

Note that the `handleMail` function encapsulates `getMailToSend` and `sendMail`, which call each other. Be warned, current JavaScript has a limit to the number of cycles this can go through until your call stack grows too big, which is a **stack overflow!**

Finally, writing this kind of async code is prone to programmer error. I highly recommend choosing a library to do it for you. A popular one (which I favour) is [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async), but there are many to choose from. In the case above `async.whilst` can help you.

Aside - The following code tests call stack size:

```
var i = 0;

function a(){
    i += 1;
    a();
}

a();
```

Gives `i = 24275` in Node.js v0.10.26.

Comment: Ok, it helps but if the getMailToSend takes more than timer, there is two execution or more at a time... not entirely what I want :-/

Comment: So you want to wait until one send is finished before starting the next?

Comment: yeah it could seems stupid but there is real point doing that on my context, to long to explain.

Comment: Let me revise the answer for you.

Comment: Hum, new ones fear me for the infinte recursivity, no idea of the JS way but in Java, it will crash the JVM. I give you the answer cause the setInterval solves a good parts (and for others questions I have'nt ask yet :p)

Comment: I added a note about that at the end. Until ES6 proper tail calls get into Node, there is a limit to the number of cycles that can be made. I've rarely seen that issue really appear though.

Comment: I edited your post for an example of stack. Thanks for the help